# Expand all and collapse all function in js

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am new to JS and HTML. I am working on this code.

HTML

```
<style>
.Hidden {
display:none;
}
.ExpandCollapse {
cursor:pointer;
float:left;
margin-right:5px;
width:8px;
}
.Folder {
}
</style>
<body>
<ul onclick="takeAction(event);">
<div id="Folder{0}" class="ExpandCollapse">+</div>
<div class="Folder">Click to expand 0
    <ul id="ExpandCollapseFolder{0}" class="Hidden">Hidden Text 0</ul>
</div>
<div id="Folder{1}" class="ExpandCollapse">+</div>
<div class="Folder">Click to expand 1
    <ul id="ExpandCollapseFolder{1}" class="Hidden">Hidden Text 1</ul>
</div>
</ul>
</body>
```

JS

```
function takeAction(e) {
var node = e.srcElement === undefined ? e.target : e.srcElement;
var id = node.getAttribute("id");
if (id !== null && id.indexOf("Folder") > -1) {
    if (node.innerHTML == "-") {
        node.innerHTML = "+";
        document.getElementById("ExpandCollapse" + id).style.display = "none";
    } else if (node.innerHTML == "+") {
        node.innerHTML = "-";
        document.getElementById("ExpandCollapse" + id).style.display = "block";
    }
}
}
```

UPDATED

Whenever I click the "+" sign it expands whatever is in there in division having id "ExpandCollapseFolder{index}"

I want to include one Expand all and one collapse all button. Please suggest the modifications.

Comment: Can you explain with your own words what your code is or should be doing? Makes it easier to answer your question.

Comment: this is the fiddle but somehow its not working here as I want but its working perfectly in my html page http://jsfiddle.net/nhL7K/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jquery

HTML

```
<ul id='expandWrapper'>
    <div id="Folder{0}" class="ExpandCollapse">+</div>
    <div class="Folder">Click to expand 0
       <ul id="ExpandCollapseFolder{0}" class="Hidden">Hidden Text 0</ul>
    </div>
    <div id="Folder{1}" class="ExpandCollapse">+</div>
    <div class="Folder">Click to expand 1
        <ul id="ExpandCollapseFolder{1}" class="Hidden">Hidden Text 1</ul>
    </div>
</ul>


$('#expandWrapper').on('click','.ExpandCollapse',function(){
    var self = this;
    $($(this).parent().find('.Folder ul')).each(function(i,item){
        if($(item).attr('id').indexOf($(self).attr('id')) >0 )
        {
            $(item).toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3e2XP/)

JS version

```
function takeAction(e) {
    var node = e.srcElement === undefined ? e.target : e.srcElement;
    var id = node.getAttribute("id");
    if (id !== null && id.indexOf("Folder") > -1) {
        if (node.innerHTML == "-") {
            node.innerHTML = "+";
            document.getElementById("ExpandCollapse" + id).style.display = "none";
        } else if (node.innerHTML == "+") {
            node.innerHTML = "-";
            document.getElementById("ExpandCollapse" + id).style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}

var ul = document.getElementById('expandWrapper');
ul.onclick = takeAction;
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Fz2Fu/2/)

Comment: This is the fiddle I wrote using JS .. can you tell why it isnt working ?? I want to make it work just like yours http://jsfiddle.net/Fz2Fu/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you want but I guess it's something like this:

```
<script>
    function toggleIt(div) {
        var hiddenUl = document.getElementById('ExpandCollapse' + div.id);
        if (hiddenUl.getAttribute('class') == 'Shown') {
            hiddenUl.setAttribute('class', 'Hidden');
            div.innerHTML = '+';
        } 
        else {
            hiddenUl.setAttribute('class', 'Shown');
            div.innerHTML = '-';
        }
    }

    function toggleAll() {
        var toggles = document.querySelectorAll('div[onclick="toggleIt(this)"]');
        for (var i = 0; i < toggles.length; i++)
            toggleIt(toggles[i]);
    }
</script>

<style>
.Shown {
    display:block;
}
.Hidden {
display:none;
}
.ExpandCollapse {
cursor:pointer;
float:left;
margin-right:5px;
width:8px;
}
.Folder {
}
</style>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="toggleAll()" value="toggle all" />
    <br />

    <div id="Folder{0}" class="ExpandCollapse" onclick="toggleIt(this)">+</div>
    <div class="Folder">Click to expand 0
        <ul id="ExpandCollapseFolder{0}" class="Hidden">Hidden Text 0</ul>
    </div>

    <div id="Folder{1}" class="ExpandCollapse" onclick="toggleIt(this)">+</div>
    <div class="Folder">Click to expand 1
        <ul id="ExpandCollapseFolder{1}" class="Hidden">Hidden Text 1</ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

It's way easier to give every toggle-element it's own onclick function than do everything with just one in a parent node.
I hope those lines of code help you understanding that I mean.